# disable smart quotes ubuntu server 16 and desktop 16

Tags: 16.04, keyboard

I am getting smart quotes instead of straight quotes, I want straight quotes.

I have a small problem that I can't seem to fix. I recently installed Ubuntu server 16 on an old dell r210, and then installed Ubuntu desktop over it so I can have a GUI. In the process of updating all my r scripts, I noticed I could no longer type quotations as plain straight quotes, only smart quotes would appear.

I am simply pressing <kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>´</kbd> to get `¨`. I get an error in r basically saying I have **an unexpected symbol**. Further examination revealed a smart quote. Smart quotes also show up when I type quotes into firefox and the terminal. I tried switching keyboards, reinstalling r, and rstudio - didn't help.

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem, turned out my text entry was set to use the input source "English (US, international with dead keys)"

This setting is found under Settings -> Keyboard -> Text Entry (bottom left for me)

Removing this and setting it to regular English US did the trick!

Answer (score 0):

I removed ubuntu server, and installed ubuntu 16 desktop alone. This solved the problem. I still do not know why this happens in ubuntu server.

Answer (score 0):

At my Ubuntu 16.04 desktop (in any window, firefox, shell, ssh shell) pressing

```
<Alt Gr>-'
```

Gets me a straight single quote: '
and pressing:

```
<Alt Gr><shift>-"
```

Gets me a straight double quote: "
All done using US keyboard layout (with Euro on 5) that has the  `'"` key located next to Enter key.

It does not actually turn it off, but gets my work done.